# Function to generate random numbers that are different by at least 2

Tags: php

I am looking to generate a series of random numbers that have a difference of at least 2 from the previous number that was generated. I thought that a simple function that would call itself would be the way to go - see code below...

```
function getRandomLength($previous){
    $x = rand(1,12);

    if(abs($x - $previous) > 2){
        return $x;
    } else {
        getRandomLength($previous);
    }
}
```

For whatever reason, this is not working out the way that I had hoped it would. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

And for those wondering why I want random numbers that are slightly different, I'm building a deck. I need to cut the decking boards and I don't want the joint to line up, or have any perceivable pattern to them, hence, I turn to my trusty random number generator to help out...

Comment: A simple solution: multiply by 2

Comment: Please describe what it's doing, and what it should be doing...

Comment: One thing that's wrong for sure is that you're not returning the value of your recursive function call. Try `else { return getRandomLength($previous);`

Comment: Also, don't declare a global. Use `var $x = rand(1,12)`;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two problems here:

```
function getRandomLength($previous){
    $x = rand(1,12);

    if(abs($x - $previous) > 2){
```

First problem is here - you use `> 2` when you meant `>= 2`, e.g. if the difference is two or more then it's fine.

```
        return $x;
    } else {
        getRandomLength($previous);
```

Second problem is here - you call the method again, but you do not return the result of calling it, so the result of the method will be an un-useful `null`.

Also, you should not code the method to be recursive, it should be iterative, as it doesn't need recursive logic.

```
    }
}
```

Comment: Adding the return to the else statement fixed it.

Comment: >2 is fine, I don't see why you think the OP meant >1. Not returning the recursive call is definitely wrong; Agreed that an iterative solution is a lot simpler.

Comment: @Juan Mendes Simple. The OP's desire is to return random numbers that are different by at least 2. 3 is different from 1 by at least 2. abs(3-1) is 2. 2 is not > 2.

Comment: I did completely miss the call to `abs` :), it doesn't need to be there at all, does it?

Comment: @Juan Mendes Yes it does. He wants them to be different by at least 2 in either direction. e.g if previous is 3, 1 should be ok and 5 should be ok as well. abs(5-3) is 2, abs(1-3) is also 2. Both should pass.

Comment: I think I see, assuming that `rand()` returns integers only, then >1 would work...

Comment: @Juan Mendes I changed the answer to only recommend `>= 2`

Answer (score -1):

Since you need an offset of at least 2, pick a random number starting from 0 and add 2 to it. Since it's an offset, you add it to the previous value (but I'm sure you could figure that out).

Comment: rand(); result: 5. +2 = 7
rand(); result: 5 + 2 = 7... equal!

Comment: I've overread that "add it to the previous value" thing I guess